# Iterate Firestore Data using "ngx-datatable" in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use `ngx-datatable` to make the table responsive in my website.

I try this tutorial on Youtube (https://youtu.be/IptxeHSuhko) but unfortunately, the data is not showing when I used `ngx-datatable`.

I try the code but its already buggy, this is the image screenshot, it only shows the fourth column:
[image]

I try to console.log the records in Subscription method, fortunately it fetched the correct data:
[image]

**audit-trail.html**

```
<div class="ion-padding">
  <ngx-datatable
  class="material"
  [limit]="8"
  [rows]="rows"
  [rowHeight]="50"
  [columns]="columns"
  [columnMode]="'force'"
  [headerHeight]="50"
  [footerHeight]="50"
  [scrollbarV]="true"
  [scrollbarH]="true">

    <ngx-datatable-column name="Surname">
      <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">{{ value }}</ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>

    <ngx-datatable-column name="First Name">
      <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">{{ value }}</ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>

    <ngx-datatable-column name="Student ID">
      <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">{{ value }}</ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>

    <ngx-datatable-column name="Action">
      <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">{{ value }}</ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>

    <ngx-datatable-column name="Timestamp">
      <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">{{ value }}</ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
  </ngx-datatable>
</div>
```

**audit-trail.ts**

```
export class AuditTrailPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  rows;
  columns;


  constructor(private menu: MenuController,
              private afs: AngularFirestore,
              private auditService: AuditTrailService
    )
    {
      this.getData();
    }

  ngOnInit() {
 
  }

  getData() {
    this.afs.collection('audit').valueChanges().subscribe((records) => {
      this.rows = records;
      console.log(records);
    });
  }
```

Is there a way to iterate the data in Firestore using ngx-datatable

Comment: Can you try to make console.log(records) inside the subscription method to check if you're receiving the data correctly

Comment: I already added the results. I get the correct data from the console.log

Comment: I don't see where you set 'this.columns' to tell the table where to get its data

Comment: According to the tutorial, the column was set on the html file and there is no `this.columns` on TS side.

Comment: Look at 5:12 in the video

Comment: Yes, but he removed it on the other half of the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate the data in Firestore using `ngx-datatable`, user must set a `prop` attribute to the column.

More info: https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/api/column/inputs#prop-string

**Option 1 - in HTML file**

```
    <ngx-datatable-column name="Surname" prop="userSurname">
      <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">{{ value }}</ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
```

**Option 2 - in TS file**

```
  getData() {
    this.afs.collection('audit', ref => ref.orderBy("createdAt", "desc")).valueChanges().subscribe((records) => {
      this.rows = records;
      this.columns = [
         { prop: 'userSurname', name: 'Surname'},
         { prop: 'userName', name: 'First Name'},
         { prop: 'userSchoolId', name: 'School ID'}, 
         { prop: 'action', name: 'Action'},
         { prop: 'createdAt', name: 'Timestamp'}
      ];
    });
```